# Feedback on attempt at solution to $P(A \cup B \cup C) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(A\cap C) - P(A\cap B) -\cdots$

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory, inclusion-exclusion

Verify: $P(A \cup B \cup C) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(A\cap C) - P(A\cap B) - P(A\cap C) - P(B \cap C) + P(A \cap B \cap C)$

I have looked around on the site and seen solutions for the question, but what I was looking for here is feedback on where I went wrong in my attempt at the solution and is there a way for me to reconcile what I did with the solutions that I have seen here?

**Attempt**

1) Decomposed $A \cup B \cup C$ into a collection of disjoint subsets:

$$D = A \cap B^{c} \cap C^{c} \\ E = A^{c} \cap B \cap C^{c} \\ F = A^{c} \cap B^{c} \cap C \\
G = A \cap B \cap C^{c} \\ H = A \cap B^{c} \cap C \\ I = A^{c} \cap B \cap C \\ J = A \cap B \cap C$$

2) By the fundamental axioms of probability:

$$P(A \cup B \cup C) = P(D) + P(E) + P(F) + P(G) + P(H) + P(I) + P(J)$$

Observe that:

$$ A = D \cup G \cup  H \cup J \\ B = E \cup G \cup I \cup J \\ C = F \cup H \cup I \cup J$$

Therefore we can say

$$P(A) + P(B) + P(C) = P(D) + P(E) + P(F) + P(G) + P(H) + P(I) + P(J) + P(E) + P(G) + P(I) + P(J) + P(F) + P(H) + P(I) + P(J) \\ \Rightarrow P(A) + P(B) + P(C) = P(A \cup B \cup C) + P(G) + P(H) + P(I) + 2P(J) $$

Rearranging terms then yields:

$$  P(A \cup B \cup C) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(G) - P(H) - P(I) - 2P(J) \\ = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(A \cap B) - P(A\cap C ) - P(B \cap C) - 2P(A \cap B \cap C)$$

As can be seen, everything works out except for that last term....So where did I go wrong in my approach? I feel I didn't treat an intersection of sets in the correct way.

Comment: Okay... let's see.  Your setup is fine.  Wit this many letters though, it gets very difficult to read.  It would help if you at least group terms where possible, maybe using some underbraces to write notes or something and dropping the $P$'s to enhance readability.  Letting lowercase letter be the probability of the corresponding event, like $a+b+c=\underbrace{\left(d+g+h+j\right)}_{a}+\underbrace{\left(e+g+i+j\right)}_{b}+\underbrace{\left(f+h+i+j\right)}_{c}$

Answer (score 1):

At a glance, it looks like your mistake is on the last line.

$P(A\cup B\cup C)=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)\color{red}{-P(G)}\color{blue}{-P(H)}\color{green}{-P(I)}-2P(J)$

$=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)\color{red}{-P(A\cap B)}\color{blue}{-P(A\cap C)}\color{green}{-P(B\cap C)}-2P(A\cap B\cap C)$

It appears that you thought that $P(G)$ was equal to $P(A\cap B)$ and similarly with the others, but that is not quite right.  Instead $P(A\cap B)=P(G)+P(J)$

So, adding and subtracting $P(J)$ (*which is equivalent to having added zero and is perfectly fine to do*) for each of these we get:

$P(A\cup B\cup C)=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)\color{red}{-P(G)}\color{blue}{-P(H)}\color{green}{-P(I)}-2P(J)\\\underbrace{\color{red}{-P(J)}+P(J)}_{=0}\color{blue}{-P(J)}+P(J)\color{green}{-P(J)}+P(J)$

Using *both* red terms for $P(A\cap B)$ and similarly for the others, and seeing $-2P(J)+3P(J)$ for a total of $+1P(J)$ and replacing, this gives:

$=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(A\cap B)-P(A\cap C)-P(B\cap C)+P(A\cap B\cap C)$

Comment: The mistake I made with regards to $P(A \cap B) = P(G) + P(J)$ makes sense to me. I'm aware of the "adding zero" trick, but if I had gotten to this stage I probably would not have thought about using it. What I'm asking is, what brought up the intuition to use the trick? Was it just based solely on you were aware of what you wanted to arrive at and it so happens that adding zero would work? or was there a deeper reasoning?

Answer (score 1):

It might be less of a confusion to break it down into two steps.

Firstly show for *any* two events $X$, $Y$ that: $$\small\begin{align}\mathsf P(X\cup Y)&=\mathsf P(X\smallsetminus Y)+\mathsf P(X\cap Y)+\mathsf P(Y\smallsetminus X)\\&~~\vdots\\&=\mathsf P(X)+\mathsf P(Y)-\mathsf P(X\cap Y)\end{align}$$

So now you can extend this to *any* three events $A$, $B$, and $C$:$$\small\begin{align}\mathsf P(A\cup B\cup C)&=\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B\cup C)-\mathsf P(A\cap (B\cup C))\\&=\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B\cup C)-\mathsf P((A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C))\\&~~\vdots\\&=\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)+\mathsf P(C)-\mathsf P(A\cap B)-\mathsf P(A\cap C)-\mathsf P(B\cap C)+\mathsf P(A\cap B\cap C)\end{align}$$